# Using TFS and by passing another developers error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, compilation, compiler-errors

I have done a bit of googling, and I cannot seem to find a solution.

I work on a VS 2013 project with 1 other person. Some times the developer doesn't check everything in, or has errors in the code. I do not always have the ability/authority to make the other developer to correct the errors.

How do I continue being able to compile the parts of the project I am working on, with out having to ask the other developer to check in or solve the errors.

Just to clarify, we are working on two separate forms/files that do not interact with each other. Is there a way to compile the current form I am working on, and run from the last successful build on the forms that have errors?

As the Title says,I am using TFS, and maybe that can be part of the solution?

Is what I am asking for possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement a gated check-in build in order to prevent developers to check-in code that doesn't compile.
If they really want to put the code that is not complete in Source Control they should use the shelvesets.

Comment: Okay, that will defiantly help in some cases.

However, lets say the other developer checks in 1/3 of the files being worked on (those three files referencing each other).

There will be no errors on there side, but when I do a get latest, It will only update one of the files on my side (and now there are missing references to the other 2 files, because the other files are not updated yet).

Comment: If the other developer checks in 1 of files that he has been working on and the gated check-in build succeeds (meaning that what is Source Control at the check-in moment plus the changeset of that file compiles with no errors) then it should compile also when you do a Get Latest Version (assuming that the changes that you are working on are compiling)

Comment: Thanks I googled the gated check in. This seems like a proactive way of preventing these errors, thus solving my problem. I will accept it as an answer.